# Windows 2008 R2 - How do I reinstall "Client for Microsoft Networks"

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2

Through a series of unfortunate events, my network adapter no longer has "Client for Microsoft Networks" installed.

The machine is windows 2008 R2 (x64) - What is the best way to recover this vital component on the adapter?

Answer (score 3):

Go into the properties of the network adapter, click the Install button below the network component list, select Client and hit the Add button. If the Client for Microsoft Networks is listed there you'll be able to reinstall it from there.

Comment: +1, And if "Client for MS Networks" isn't in that list, you're in the deep stuff.

Comment: Deep stuff indeed. I'm assuming that because the component was uninstalled that it will be available in the list. It's not available on a system that it's not been uninstalled from and I don't have a convenient system to uninstall it from as a test.